# RC522 board not working, red led is on

Tags: arduino, rfid, mfrc522

I have a RFID RC522 board that was working perfectly, until by mistake I tried to write it with a phone as if it was a RFID tag and now it stopped working, in the way that its led still turns on but it's not recognised by the code (it says firmware version 0x0).

I guess writing it fried the chip, but is there any way to check if it's actually fried or just a software problem?

Comment: Can you scope the input to reader? RFD can handle 4V max with 2kV ESD as long as inputs don’t exceed supply which if not discharge by static to conductors is pretty robust .

Comment: I was using it with an Arduino with the 3.3V pin but I realised the serial connection was from the Arduino so I guess running on 5V however what surprised me is that I was able to perfectly read any tag, I even tried some not provided with the board, and they were all working until I tried with my android phone and NFC tools pro but I used the "write" option instead of emulating a card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MFRC522 does not support Card emulation mode, When you put both PCD chips in writer mode across each other(Phone and RC522), generated field by the phone may damaged the RC522, but any way there is a version register in MFRC522 chip, try to read this register,if it was not returned successfully,means your rc522 is damaged.